# Make it more obvious that the change I'm reviewing is a new topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I've found myself sometimes getting confused whether the edit I opened up is a new topic or just an edit to an existing topic, because there's nothing on the actual review screen that explicitly says "new topic" - but the proposed changes list *does* differentiate between "edited" and "new topic" (though fairly subtly) so this is clearly available information.

It's inconvenient to have to leave the page and go back to the list and check and then go back to the review screen. Could there be a banner or text somewhere (probably at the right next to the rest of the edit information) that makes it more **blatantly obvious** that the edit I'm reviewing creates a new topic?

Making this obvious is immensely helpful in making sure we don't create duplicate topics without noticing it wasn't just adding new examples to an existing topic but actually creating a new one with the same name.

**Note:** This is pretty obvious if the topic is created based on a request, because it adds a big blue box at the top with the topic request information in it. However, if you just create a topic straight out without a request for it, no such information exists.

Comment: Not to mention that if it is a duplicate it's a chore to go find the other one(s) just to be sure and provide requested link when rejecting as duplicate